# CakePHP 2.1.0: "Under Maintenance" Page

Tags: exception, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to implement something like [Mark Story's "Down for Maintenance" page](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/quick-and-dirty-down-for-maintenance-page-with-cakephp) using CakePHP 2.1.0. This is what I have so far:

app/Config/bootstrap.php:

`Configure::write('App.maintenance', true);`

app/Controller/AppController.php:

```
if (Configure::read('App.maintenance')) {
    App::uses('UnderMaintenanceException', 'Error/Exception');
    throw new UnderMaintenanceException();
}
```

Finally, I have a file located at "app/Lib/Error/Exception/UnderMaintenanceException.php", but it's blank because I'm not sure what to put in it. How can I make it a friendly-looking "We're down for maintenance" page regardless of whether or not debug is set to 0? Thank you!

**EDIT:** I realize now that my question is somewhat unclear. So I put the following in my "app/Lib/Error/Exception/UnderMaintenanceException.php" file:

```
<?php
class UnderMaintenanceException extends HttpException {}
```

Now when I go to any page, I get this output:

```
Fatal Error (256): [UnderMaintenanceException] 
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_project/app/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php(12): AppController->beforeFilter()
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_project/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(232): AppExceptionRenderer->_outputMessage('error500')
#2 [internal function]: ExceptionRenderer->error500(Object(UnderMaintenanceException))
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_project/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(165): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_project/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(127): ExceptionRenderer->render()
#5 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(UnderMaintenanceException))
#6 {main} [CORE/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 136]
```

If I change my debug value to 0, I get no output. Not very friendly! What can I do to have friendly output either way?

Comment: What are you actually asking? What to put in the down for maintenance page?

Comment: @Juhana Sorry for the lack of clarity. I updated my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP 2.1.0: How to Create "Down for Maintenance" Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674696/cakephp-2-1-0-how-to-create-down-for-maintenance-page)

Answer (score 0):

Just override the constructor in the new class you have created, as follows:

```
<?php

/**
 * Represents an 'Under Maintenance Error'
*/
class UnderMaintenanceException extends HttpException {

    /**
    * Constructor
    *
    * @param string $message If no message is given, it defaults to
    *                       'Application is Under Maintenance'
    * @param int $code Status code, defaults to 403
    */
    public function __construct($message = null, $code = 403) {
        if (empty($message)) {
            $message = 'Application is Under Maintenance';
        }
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }
}
```

Some might argue that the proper status code to return is 503 (Service Unavailable). And they would be right. However, due to how CakePHP 2.x handles 5xx errors, the only error visible to users in production would be 'An Internal Error Has Occurred', which is not very descriptive. 4xx errors pass to the user the error message, but no so erros 5xx.

To be able to return status 503 together with a descriptive message, ExceptionRenderer needs to be extended and the function error500($error) overridden.